# Declaring variables in macros in C, allowing a trailing semicolon

Tags: c, macros

This is a silly problem with macro declarations, but one I've run into a few times and was curious if there is some solution I'm missing.

I have a macro that declares variables, which I want to ensure are not initialized by mistake.

```
#define DECLARE_FOO(var) \
    int _##var##_a = 0; \
    int _##var##_b = 0
```

Example use:

```
DECLARE_FOO(var);
```

however this allows...

```
DECLARE_FOO(var) + 1;
```

I could just ignore this *(for now Im just leaving it this way)*, but I'd like to disallow it. simple...

```
#define DECLARE_FOO(var) \
    int _##var##_a = 0; \
    int _##var##_b = 0;
```

However now I have to remove the semicolon from the declaration otherwise I get this warning.

```
DECLARE_FOO(var);
int bar;
```

`ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Werror=declaration-after-statement]`

So, I have to do this...

```
DECLARE_FOO(var)
int bar;
```

...which expands correctly, but looks odd for anyone reading the code and not checking the macro definition. Also editors that don't expand macros may warn about this as incorrect syntax.

Is there some way to disallow assignments to the variable but also end usage of the declaration with a semicolon ?

### Update

It wasn't really clear in my question, but `-Werror=declaration-after-statement` infers that C90 is a requirement here, answers mixing in statements wont work in this case since there may be proceeding declarations.

Comment: Why are you still programming against the C90 standard? We can mix code and declarations in C since 1999. So just switch to a more modern dialect, and your compiler will ignore the double semicolon.

Comment: @cmaster Because of compatibility with MSVC2008, which still forbids mixed declarations and code. (Even though I use GCC 4.8 and Clang on Linux)

Answer (score 4):

Add a no-op expression to the macro:

```
#define DECLARE_FOO(var) \
    int _##var##_a = 0; \
    int _##var##_b = 0; \
    (void) 0
```

BTW: this will even *fail* if the macro is used *without* a semicolon.

UPDATE: another trick: make the last line of the macro an *external* declaration (which also is a no-op, but will choke without a semicolon)

```
#define DECLARE_FOO(var) \
    int _##var##_a = 0; \
    int _##var##_b = 0; \
    extern int _##var##_ext
```

Comment: This gives the warning/error, `ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code`

Comment: Only if you call the macto twice in a row. c99 _does_ allow mixed code and declarations.

Comment: Not just calling twice in a row, but defining _any_ variables after it, which makes it rather limited.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that.

Comment: Nice find regarding extern use!, Though then you end up with a dummy var in the name-space, and I now get a warning from GCC that its unused, its still probably the closest thing to an answer so far.

Comment: For an _external_ reference you get a warning? heve you ever read header files; they are full of (unused) external references, filling up the namespaces.

Comment: right, if the `extern` is declared in the function scope, GCC warns thats not used, declaring `extern` outside the function has no problems (therefor headers don't give this warning from `extern`s).

Answer (score 0):

As long as mixing decelerations and statements is not allowed (C90), then it is not possible to guard against trailing text after the macro.

However it is possible to use ternary operator to ignore the trailing text, this is a fairly poor solution (and I wouldn't recommend its use).

```
#define DECLARE_FOO(var) \
    int _##var##_a = 0; \
    int _##var##_b = 1 ? 0 : 0
```

This won't raise an error, but the `+ 1` will be ignored.

```
DECLARE_FOO(var) + 1;
```